# maxDistance in mongodb : issue in finding near by data

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, location, mongodb-query

My mongo version is 3.2.6

My tables is restaurant_locations.

I have given index as below:

```
db.restaurant_locations._ensureIndex({'location': '2dsphere'});
```

Data stored in this table is as below:

```
> db.restaurant_locations.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573ff477df3c12bdd6463d07"),
        "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        72.5220332,
                        23.0656791
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573ff5badf3c12bdd6463d08"),
        "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        62.5220332,
                        13.0656791
                ]
        }
}
```

Now when I fire below query:

```
db.restaurant_locations.find({
  location: {
    $near: {
        $geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [ 70, 20 ]
        },
    $maxDistance: 100000000
    }
  }
});
```

I get both the records as output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("573ff477df3c12bdd6463d07"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 72.5220332, 23.0656791 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("573ff5badf3c12bdd6463d08"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 62.5220332, 13.0656791 ] } }
```

Now, when I execute below query:

```
db.restaurant_locations.find({
  location: {
    $near: {
        $geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [ 70, 20 ]
        },
    $maxDistance: 1000000
    }
  }
});
```

I get only one record as output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("573ff477df3c12bdd6463d07"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 72.5220332, 23.0656791 ] } }
```

1. I am not getting exactly how $maxDistance work.
2. I want to find restaurants within a distance of 10 kms, then what's the exact thing, I need to pass in $maxDistance?
3. Suppose my co-ordinates are 40 and 20, so if I want restaurants within 10kms, will above two records display?

I have referred many mongodb docs, stackoverflow questions, but am not getting exact idea, how it works

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

*`I am not getting exactly how $maxDistance work.`*

in order to get the maxDistance work  you  have to  use the `$nearSphere` function

your query will be something like this:

```
location: {
    $nearSphere: {
        $geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [ 70, 20 ]
        },
    $maxDistance: 10000
    }
  }
```

*`I want to find restaurants within a distance of 10 kms,`*

you have to  multiply this  by  1000 as mongo resolution is in  meters

*`Suppose my co-ordinates are 40 and 20, so if I want restaurants within 10kms, will above two records display?`*

Yes but you have to be sure  that you specify the longitude first, then latitude.

Comment: I executed query specified by you, but still its not giving any output, if I replace "10000" to "1000000", am getting one record